# Cauchy goursat's theorem and holomorphicity

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, holomorphic-functions

If f is continuous on the unit disc and holomorphic on the punctured disc, why does this imply that f is holomorphic on the entire disc?

Comment: holomorphicity $\rightarrow$ holomorphy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In complex analysis we can't do anything without the Cauchy integral theorem. Here is how you can use it :

If $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $U = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, \ 0< |z| < 1, z \ne s\}$ then for $r < 1-\epsilon, \epsilon < |s| < r-\epsilon$ the contour $\{|z| = r\}$ is homotopically equivalent to $\{|z| = \epsilon\} \ \ \cup \ \ \{|z-s| =\epsilon\}$ on $U$, so that
$$\int_{|z| = r} g(z)dz=\int_{|z| = \epsilon} g(z)dz+\int_{|z-s| = \epsilon} g(z)dz$$

Applying it to $\displaystyle\frac{f(z)}{z-s}$, $0 < |s| < r$  you get

$$\int_{|z| = r}\frac{f(z)}{z-s}dz = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|z| = \epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{z-s}dz+\int_{|z-s| = \epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{z-s}dz\qquad\qquad $$ $$\qquad\qquad=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|z| = \epsilon}(\frac{f(0)}{-s}+o(1))dz +\int_{|z-s| = \epsilon}\frac{f(s)+o(1)}{z-s}dz = 2i \pi f(s)$$

The LHS is clearly holomorphic (and analytic) in $s$ on $|s| < r$, hence so is the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Write a Laurent series for $f$ in the annulus $0<|z|<1$. If $f$ is continuous at $0$, what does that tell you about the coefficients of $z^{-n}$, $n=1,2,\dots$?

Comment: It is convergent and analytic?

Comment: Hence holomorphic, in fact, at $0$.

Comment: But we haven't learnt Laurent series yet... Can we use Goursat's theorem to prove it? That's the theorem that we are learning right now so I suppose it can be proved using Goursat's theorem?

Comment: Have you proved Morera’s Theorem? Doesn't Cauchy-Goursat assume complex differentiable everywhere inside a simple closed curve?

Comment: I haven't, but it would be proved in tomorrow's lecture, so I guess we can use that.

Comment: Great. Figure it out :)

Comment: So this is Morera's thoerem?

Comment: No, no. I'm saying you can prove your homework question by using Morera's Theorem. Wait for lecture or find it in your text.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as $f$ is bounded in a punctured neighbourhood of $0$, the singularity at $0$ is [removable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).

Comment: Is this a theorem?

Comment: @J.doe Yes, whose proof we just gave :)